# How do I remove the brackets and the comma from the hover tooltip on my Plotly.js scatter plot?

Tags: formatting, hover, tooltip, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I posted this over at the Plotly community here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-i-remove-brackets-and-comma-from-hover-tooltip-on-my-scatter-plot/79008. I'm repeating it here to get more responses.

I'm trying to format the hover tooltip on my Plotly.js scatter plot. Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

I managed to get it to round to 2 decimal place, add the units, and put the x value and y value on different lines. Now I would like to remove the brackets and the comma, or at least put the comma on the first line.

How can I do that?

Here is my layout:

CODE:

```
{
...
   "yaxis":{
...
        hoverformat: '.2f',
        ticksuffix: ' ' + $scope.unit
   },
   "hovermode":"closest",
   "xaxis":{
...
        hoverformat: '.2f',
        ticksuffix: ' ' + driver.unit + '<br>'
   }
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
...
   "yaxis":{
...
      "hoverformat":".2f",
      "ticksuffix":" kWh"
   },
   "hovermode":"closest",
   "xaxis":{
...
      "hoverformat":".2f",
      "ticksuffix":" °C<br>"
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the [`hovertemplate`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate). See also https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/#hovertemplate